# What is the correct terminology for that frictional / momentum-based scrolling effect found on some websites?

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling, vertical-scroll

I've been coming across a lot of websites recently that have a very satisfying friction / momentum-based scrolling effect on them. An example would be https://useplink.com/en/. I've been searching for the correct terminology for this effect for a very long time but I could never find what I was looking for (guides, tutorials, libraries & e.t.c. that could help me understand how it works). If anyone knows what this is correctly referred to as or has any libraries related to it an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not a programming question; possibly belongs on [ux.se] instead.

Comment: I posted it here since I figured that to achieve the effect you have to do some sort of frontend coding, and then based on previous smooth-scrolling implementations I've seen before I assumed that coding would be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Even if it was on topic, that's still "seeking library recommendations" which is opinion based.

Comment: I guess, but the question is more or less seeking the actual terminology used for this sort of effect. I'll go post it over there if this gets downvoted beyond infinity.

Comment: @imcanada These types of sites are a usability and accessibility nightmare.  Very rarely is there a good use case for them.  Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an official name for it, I have heard, momentum scrolling, inertia and kinetic scrolling, on that last one there is a set of 5 good articles here that you can take a look to get a grasp around the concept:

https://ariya.io/tags/kinetic

Comment: Thank you, after reading those posts and a bit more digging, this time using 'inertia as a keyword, I stumbled across this plugin here https://min30327.github.io/luxy.js/ which seems to do exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped getting you in the right direction!